# A way to programatically generating background with ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am connecting to an XML back-end to create different "pages" for a flash website. (I know.) And I'm wondering if there is a way to programatically generate a background that will automatically be the correct height for the content within each "page". My background is in the form of a seamless tiled graphic. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand.

If you've got xml generating the pages, can't you have attributes for page dimensions ?

e.g.

```
<pages>
<page title="bla bla" width="760" height="600">
<!-- content nodes etc. -->
</page>
</pages>
```

you would get the right width,height values from xml.

as for the tiles, have a look at the [beginBitmapFill()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/00001895.html) method in the documentation.

Goodluck!

Comment: Well I hadn't thought about that, but I think I'll do that dependent upon the number of records I have so it makes it large enough. Thanks, sometimes you just need outside insight.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out [Degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/)  for [bitmap fills](http://www.degrafa.org/source/BitmapFill/BitmapFill.html).